# Matlab R2015a COM connection (actxserver) with MS Excel 2013

Tags: excel, matlab

Platform: Win 7 64 bit, Matlab R2015a, MS Office Professional Plus 2013

Problem: Matlab R2015a - COM connection (actxserver) with MS Excel 2013.

The same code that was working before with Excel 2007 or Excel 2010 is now giving me the following error. Any help to solve this problem is appreciated.

```
Error using Interface.000208DB_0000_0000_C000_000000000046/Open
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
Source: Microsoft Excel
Description: Open method of Workbooks class failed
Help File: xlmain11.chm
Help Context ID: 0

Error in funWriteExcelAllResults (line 174)
Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(excelOutputFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing my code I think I have found the reason:

```
//% Reference to Image Analyst: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers
//% /87487-i-have-excel-2003-and-2010-
//% installed-but-xlsread-fails-to-import-a-simple-xlsx-file

excelVersion = str2double(Excel.Version)
if excelVersion < 12
    excelExtension = '.xls';
else
    excelExtension = '.xlsx';
end
% Determine the proper format to save the files in.  
% It depends on the extension (Excel version).
switch excelExtension
    case '.xls' %xlExcel8 or xlWorkbookNormal
        xlFormat = -4143;
    case '.xlsb' %xlExcel12
        xlFormat = 50;
    case '.xlsx' %xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        xlFormat = 51;
    case '.xlsm' %xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        xlFormat = 52;
    otherwise
        xlFormat = -4143;
end


% File='C:\YourFileFolder\FileName';
File = excelOutputFileName
if ~exist(File,'file')
    Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add;
    Workbook.SaveAs(File, xlFormat);
    Workbook.Close(false);
end

Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(excelOutputFileName);
```

The last part was trying reopen the workbook that was already open, and was causing the error. I changed that into:

```
if ~exist(File,'file')
    Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add;
    Workbook.SaveAs(File, xlFormat);

else
    Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(File);
    Workbook.Save
end
```

and the problem seems to be solved. Without the Save, I was getting the following error:

```
Error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
Worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets;
```

I wonder why the previous versions of Excel were not giving me an error?